# How to safely unwrap a dictionary value in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, function, dictionary

I'm trying to safely unwrap a dictionary value that I have inside my function. I found a snippet from another question that worked but I had to force unwrap it when I was printing. Only worked when there was a sure value available.

```
func emailAddress(for name: String) -> String? {
    let emails = ["daniel":"danielsenga@yahoo.com","Kevin":"Kevin@gmail.com"]
    let email = emails[name ?? "none"]
    return email

}

print(emailAddress(for: "daniel" )!)
```

This piece of code is on and off when working. I prefer to **safely unwrap** it using **if-let** however when I enter this code to unwrap.

```
func emailAddress(for name: String) -> String? {
    let emails = ["daniel":"danielsenga@yahoo.com","Kevin":"Kevin@gmail.com"]
    if let email = emails[name] {
    print(email)
    } else {
        print("There is no email address")
    }
     return email
}
```

Swift gives me all kinds of errors and i'm not sure where the issue is. Optionals are already confusing and now for dictionaries only being optionals has made unwrapping a nightmare for me. When I use the examples online they work but my own implementation is a disaster.

I also have seen that **emails[name ?? "none"]** is a swift 5 feature. Could this be a problem?

Comment: `??` is called nil coalescing operator. It is only used to specify a default value in case your object is optional

Comment: You need to return the email after printing it and return nil in the end of your method instead of email. Don’t forget to remove the `?? “none”` it is pointless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns `String?`. The original dictionary also returns `String?`. So there is no point to unwrap the value (safely/unsafely) at all!

First thing you should do is to change return type of the function `String` (not optional).

Then you have some ways to make it safe:

### - Optional binding

```
func emailAddress(for name: String) -> String {
    let emails = ["daniel":"danielsenga@yahoo.com","Kevin":"Kevin@gmail.com"]
    if let email = emails[name] { 
        return email
    } else {
        return "none"
    }
}
```

### - Using Guard

```
func emailAddress(for name: String) -> String {
    let emails = ["daniel":"danielsenga@yahoo.com","Kevin":"Kevin@gmail.com"]
    guard let email = emails[name] else { return "none" } 
    return email 
}
```

### - Using nil coalescing

```
func emailAddress(for name: String) -> String {
    let emails = ["daniel":"danielsenga@yahoo.com","Kevin":"Kevin@gmail.com"]
    return emails[name] ?? "none"
}
```

### - Dictionary default

```
func emailAddress(for name: String) -> String {
    let emails = ["daniel":"danielsenga@yahoo.com","Kevin":"Kevin@gmail.com"]
    return emails[name, default: "none"]
}
```

Comment: or `return emails[name, default: "none"]`

Answer (score 3):

When using `if let` the `email` is visible only inside the block , You need

```
func emailAddress(for name: String) -> String {
    let emails = ["daniel":"danielsenga@yahoo.com","Kevin":"Kevin@gmail.com"]
    return emails[name] ?? "none"
}
```

---

For you code it would be like

```
func emailAddress(for name: String) -> String? {
    let emails = ["daniel":"danielsenga@yahoo.com","Kevin":"Kevin@gmail.com"]
    if let email = emails[name] {
         print(email)
         return email
     } 
     print("There is no email address")
     return nil
}
```